# Program adds two large integers using arrays in C++. It works for most numbers but fails in a certain case and I cannot pinpoint why

Tags: c++, arrays

The program uses an array to add large numbers. It works for the most part but fails if 56789101112 and 12345678910 are input. For some reason if this is input the carry doesn't get added to the next array element it just is output by itself with the sum next. For all other intents and purposes the carry works. For this example I have to use arrays to calculate the large numbers nothing else. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

const int DIGITS = 20;

void readNum(int list[], int& length, string input1);
void reverseArray(int arr[], int start, int end);
void sumNum(int list1[], int numOfElementsList1,
    int list2[], int numOfElementsList2);



int main()
{
    // Write your main here
    string input1;
    string input2;
    int list[DIGITS];
    int list2[DIGITS];
    int input1Length;
    int input2Length;
    cout << "Please enter your 1st number: " << endl;
    cin >> input1;
    cout << "Please enter your 2nd number: " << endl;
    cin >> input2;
    input1Length = input1.length();
    input2Length = input2.length();
    readNum(list, input1Length, input1);
    readNum(list2, input2Length, input2);
    reverseArray(list, 0, input1Length);
    reverseArray(list2, 0, input2Length);
    sumNum(list, input1Length, list2, input2Length);
  
   

}

void readNum(int list[], int& length, string input1)
{

    int array[DIGITS];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = input1[i] - '0';
        list[i] = array[i];
        for (int i = length; i <= DIGITS - 1; i++)
        {
            list[i] = 0;
        }
    }
  
}
void reverseArray(int arr[], int start, int length)
{
    int end;
    end = length - 1;
    while (start < end)
    {
        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
void sumNum(int list1[], int numOfElementsList1,
    int list2[], int numOfElementsList2)
{
   
    int array2[20];
    int sum = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= DIGITS - 1; i++)
    {
 
        sum = (list1[i] + list2[i]);


        if (sum >= 10)
        {
           
            array2[i] = (sum  + carry) % 10;
            carry = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            array2[i] = sum + carry;
            carry = 0;
        }

    }
    reverseArray(array2, 0, DIGITS);
    int flag = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < DIGITS; i++)
    {
        if (flag == 1 && array2[i] != 0)
            flag = 0;
        if (flag != 1)
        {
            cout << array2[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sum + carry` can this overflow?

Comment: The program is working it just it not outputting the correct answer for those two inputs. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Side note: Using a raw array of `int` plus a size variable is a very C style. Some `std::vector<int>` could make the code simpler. (Remember to pass by reference to functions which want to modify a vector.)

Comment: Sum + carry can't overflow.

Comment: I have to use an array.

Comment: Figuring out why is what a debugger is for. (However, what if `sum==9` and `carry` is `1`?)

Comment: You should use `std::array` in C++.

Comment: You can reduce your example to inputs `11` and `789`. The correct result is `800` but the actual result is `7100`.

Comment: Ok yeah i stepped through I see what is happening. If it is 9 and has a carry of 1 it overflows like you were saying. Now I just need to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: Ok. I got it fixed thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The if condition

```
if (sum >= 10)
```

only depends on `sum`. You have to check `sum + carry`. You don't even need the if condition. You can replace the block

```
sum = (list1[i] + list2[i]);

if (sum >= 10)
{
    array2[i] = (sum  + carry) % 10;
    carry = 1;
}
else
{
    array2[i] = sum + carry;
    carry = 0;
}
```

with

```
sum = list1[i] + list2[i] + carry;

array2[i] = sum % 10;
carry = sum / 10;
```